# more then three times correct answers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

i have such kind of  question,first of all  let us consider following problem

The positive integers $m > n$ leave a remainder of $2$ and $3$, respectively, when divided by $6$.

we should compare  remainder when  $(m+n)$ is divided by $6$ and  $m-n$ is  divided  by $6$,i have tried several values,like $14$ and  $9$,$26$ and $21$,$32$  and $3$,in all case i am getting same value,if such kind of question would be given on GRE ,after several numbers plugging,i got same value,could i assume that they are equal or what could i do more?if we do it algebraicaly,we  get  $m=6*k+2$   and $n=6*s+3$,

$m+n=6*(k+s)+5$

$m-n=6(k-s)-1$,remainder of first  is $5$,for second we have negative number and  $-1$ modulus $6$ is  remainder $5$,but my question basically is can i assume after three or four number plugin that i can trust given result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $m+n\equiv 2+3\equiv 5\pmod{6}$ and $m-n\equiv 2-3\equiv -1\equiv 5\pmod {6}$. So the remainders are indeed the same.

Maybe more nicely, maybe not, $(m+n)-(m-n)=2n\equiv (2)(3)\equiv 0\pmod{6}$. So the key thing was the value of $n$ modulo $6$. We have equality modulo $6$ whatever $m$ may be.

As to whether you should plug in values, that is a reasonable strategy. When you have uncertainty, it can certainly quickly eliminate several of the multiple choice options.

Unfortunately the GRE people know this, and  may sneakily make a superficially attractive option fail at values you are unlikely to try.

Comment: thanks  @Andre Nicolas,so it is better  by formulas  right

Comment: It is often quicker, and arithmetic can fail under pressure. What you need to do is exactly what you are doing: solve many sample GRE questions. Questions may not repeat, but there is a limited number of themes, and those do repeat.

Comment: yes that is what i am trying to do,i have different books and i am trying to consider as much as possible,i have exam  in 15 august

Comment: thanks for  great advice,thanks in advance